# Android : how to Filter Data From BaseAdapter Class?

Tags: android

I have a BaseAdpter Class ......The Main Activity use BaseAdapter Class to set ListView as like below,

## **CODE**

```
 ListView contactList;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    contactList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.facebookList);
    contactList.setAdapter(new **BaseAdapterClass**(this));
```

Now i use editView's addTextChangedListener here as below,

```
  searchEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             //do something to filter Base Adapter Class
    }
```

But I can understand how to use **onTextChanged()** method here to filter the base Adapter's record in which sorting is in manner to entering text in search EditBox.
please help me to achieve this.
Also please refer me if any tutorial of example related to this situation.........

Comment: Please have a look at this tutorial for using addTextChangeListener() http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html